# Truncated Mails in Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I am reading mails using Interop.Domino dll but in few cases my program hangs for a particular mail, after going through the document properties i found that the mail is truncated as a blue torn page symbol appear on it and the size property is (40K +truncated) , so is there any other property through which i can programmatically identify its a truncated mail.
I also tried accessing the size property programmatically but then the program hangs their itself.

Any help Appreciated, thanks in advance

Regards,
Haseena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to leverage Notes formulas instead of script to get your answer.  Use the NotesSession.Evaluate method to call one of the following Notes @formulas:

The **@IsDocTruncated** formula will return 1 if it is truncated and 0 if not.

The **@DocOmittedLength** formula will return the approximate number of bytes that have been omitted.